# Join table and get unique rows based on where condition

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, both tables have a column with the same value.

**Table 1**

```
|sn|Name  |Age  |Address  |Date      |
|1 |Name 1|Age 1|Address 1|18-05-2023|
|2 |Name 2|Age 2|Address 2|21-05-2023|
|3 |Name 3|Age 3|Address 3|21-05-2023|
|4 |Name 4|Age 4|Address 4|21-05-2023|
```

**Table 2**

```
|sn|student_id|addmission_no|transaction_no|Fee |transaction_date|
|10|1         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|17/05/2023      |
|11|2         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|17/05/2023      |
|12|3         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|17/05/2023      |
|13|1         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|17/05/2023      |
|14|2         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|17/05/2023      |
|15|3         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|17/05/2023      |
|16|1         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|17/05/2023      |
|17|2         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|20/05/2023      |
|18|3         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|20/05/2023      |
|19|4         |6464e25b3ad22|312009677062  |1050|20/05/2023      |
```

now I want data from both tables but only rows where **Table 1** sn matches with **Table 2** student_id and where the date in **Table 1** is 21-05-2023, it should return 3 rows.

I want the date like this.

```
<------Table 1 Data-----------------><----------Table 2 Date---------->
|sn|Name  |Age  |Address  |Date      |sn|student_id|addmission_no|Fee |
|2 |Name 2|Age 2|Address 2|21-05-2023|17|2         |6464e25b3ad22|1050|
|3 |Name 3|Age 3|Address 3|21-05-2023|18|3         |6464e25b3ad22|1050|
|4 |Name 4|Age 4|Address 4|21-05-2023|19|4         |6464e25b3ad22|1050|
```

I have tried this

> SELECT table1.sn , table1.name, table1.age, table1.address,
> table1.date, table2.sn, table2.student_id, table2.addmission_no,
> table2.Fee, FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON
> table1.sn=table2.student_id where table1.date='21-05-2023'

it gives me all the rows where student_id matches with table1.sn

Comment: Please show what you've attempted.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work due to commas, it is more likely that it was copied from Mureinik's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're only interested in the records with the most recent *transaction date* from table2.

You need to join again with a dataset of student ids and their associated max transaction date, using `group by` and `max()`

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.sn, t2.student_id, t2.addmission_no, t2.Fee
FROM   table1 t1
INNER JOIN   table2 t2 on t1.sn = t2.student_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT student_id, max(transaction_date) as max_transaction_date
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY student_id   
) as s ON s.student_id = t2.student_id AND s.max_transaction_date = t2.transaction_date
WHERE  t1.`date` = '2023-05-21'
```

Result :

| sn | Name | Age | Address | Date | sn | student_id | addmission_no | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Name 2 | Age 2 | Address 2 | 2023-05-21 | 17 | 2 | 6464e25b3ad22 | 1050 |
| 3 | Name 3 | Age 3 | Address 3 | 2023-05-21 | 18 | 3 | 6464e25b3ad22 | 1050 |
| 4 | Name 4 | Age 4 | Address 4 | 2023-05-21 | 19 | 4 | 6464e25b3ad22 | 1050 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DJqqtLqI)

Comment: it gives me the desired result but I don't want anything to do with transaction_date

Comment: How do you explain getting rows 17,18,19 from table2 ? if not by latest transaction date then it could be by `sn` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the relationship between `sn` and `student_id` and add a where clause:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM   t1
JOIN   t1.sn = t2.studdent_id
WHERE  t1.`date` = DATE'21-05-2023'
```